# Android: Show array of Images in Image View

Tags: android, arrays, imageview, adapter

I want to load array of Images one by one from drawable. At a given time the ImageView should display one image when user slides, it should load the next Image.

Can I acheive this?? I don't like gallery view, I directly need to load the single image dat fills the screen and slides through till  the end of Array.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking for hours I came up with solution as none of the answers helped me.

1. Load the **Imageview**
2. onclick will change the imageview image with an **Animation** .

**Java Code**

```
public class ImagePreviewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

        public int currentimageindex=0;
        private int[] IMAGE_IDS ={R.drawable.splash1, R.drawable.splash2, R.drawable.image_preview, R.drawable.report_incident_exclamation_mark};


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.media_preview);
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewPreview);
            imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.splash1); 
            currentimageindex++;
            imageview.setOnClickListener(this);


        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
                inFromRight.setDuration(500);
                    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageViewPreview);
                    imageview.startAnimation(inFromRight);

                if ((IMAGE_IDS.length)> currentimageindex){

                    imageview.setImageResource(IMAGE_IDS[currentimageindex]);

                    currentimageindex++;

                }


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look onto [ImageSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html). It should fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ViewFilpper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) or [`ViewSwitcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) or [`ImageSwitcher`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html) for your purposes. All these classes extend `ViewAnimator`, so they have very similar behavior and functionality, and only add a few useful function on top of what `ViewAnimator` has.

Demo: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGwG8-chUEM

Answer (score 2):

I have a different solution:

https://github.com/ysamlan/horizontalpager

It's a ViewGroup where you can add children, when swiping left or right, you will show the next or previous child in fullscreen. It's also written so that it's possible to implement vertical scrolling in case you need this.

Comment: It acts like the android homescreen, so it snaps to it's position and all that stuff..